Sikuli script does not work after switching to Mac
I switched to Mac recently and Sikuli doesn't execute anything.
I allowed screen recording for Sikuli (mac.jar file exactly), terminal and java in security settings, but this doesn't solve this issue. After the program starts, sometimes I get a message about mouse block (I can make screenshots in the app though) and even if it doesn't appear, sikuli still doesn't execute any code. Doesn't press keys, doesn't move a cursor or anything. What did I miss?
screenshot

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
